# java antilog tag

Tags: java, xml, math, mathml

i'm try for log10 calculation using mathml in xml as follow

```
<apply><log><cn>x</cn></log></apply>
```

for this i'm getting expected result, but now trying for antilog which is inverse of log, i'm not sure which tag have to be use, any i'm trying as follow

```
<apply><inverse><log><cn>x</cn></log></inverse></apply>
```

here i'm not getting the expected result, do anyone know the exact tag for the antilog

thanks

Comment: Please post code, results obtained, and expected result.

Comment: sorry, my tag was mising in previous question, so i edited it as above

Comment: AFAIK, the Java standard libraries do not support mathml calculation.  What libraries / application are you trying to use here?

Comment: sorry, my tag was mising in previous question, so i edited it as above,
so for first set i got 0 as a result and for the second set i should get 10 as a result  ( x = 1 for both set ) but i'm getting something diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base 10 antilog is just 10^x (that is, 10 raised to the *x*th power). As the link below says, the "antilog" notation is still used, but not very often. Is there a reason the normal exponential notation doesn't work for you?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilog#Antilogarithms

Answer (score 0):

Logarithms are the inverse of exponents.

If `a = logb(c)`, then `c = b ^ a` (where `^` indicates, exponentiation, not XOR).

Answer (score 0):

antilog? you mean `power`?

try

```
<msup>
  <mi>10</mi>
  <mn>x</mn>
</msup>
```

Comment: thanks bro for ur ans, but this is presentation mathml which is usually use for displaying, but i'm looking for content mathml which use for calculation

thanks